# I can't run a small script due to Foundation not being recognised

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I am a new python programmer and was testing out pyttsx3, I am trying to use nsss. However when I run the following code

```
import pyttsx3

engine=pyttsx3.init('nsss')
engine.say ("Top of the morning")
# angine=pyttsx3.init()
# angine.say("Why hello there")
# angine.runAndWait()
```

It says error Foundation module not found, so I installed it with pip install foundation. This installs foundation and django version 1.10.8 which to my understanding is not compatible with python v 3.9. But when I install Django version 3.1.7, that version is not compatible with Foundation.

The error logs are below

```
C:\Users\Ahmed_Abdelmuniem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe "C:/Users/Ahmed_Abdelmuniem/PycharmProjects/AI Engine/main.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed_Abdelmuniem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\__init__.py", line 20, in init
    eng = _activeEngines[driverName]
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed_Abdelmuniem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\weakref.py", line 134, in __getitem__
    o = self.data[key]()
KeyError: 'nsss'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed_Abdelmuniem\PycharmProjects\AI Engine\main.py", line 3, in <module>
    engine=pyttsx3.init('nsss')
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed_Abdelmuniem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\__init__.py", line 22, in init
    eng = Engine(driverName, debug)
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed_Abdelmuniem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\engine.py", line 30, in __init__
    self.proxy = driver.DriverProxy(weakref.proxy(self), driverName, debug)
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed_Abdelmuniem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\driver.py", line 50, in __init__
    self._module = importlib.import_module(name)
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed_Abdelmuniem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 790, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed_Abdelmuniem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\drivers\nsss.py", line 2, in <module>
    from Foundation import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Foundation'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score -1):

install the necessary libraries and run in separate virtual environment

```
sudo apt-get install python-espeak
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install espeak
```

using python3.9 with virtual environment,

```
python3.9 -m venv env
source env/bin/activate
pip install pyttsx3
```

now running the below demo code should work.

```
import pyttsx3
engine = pyttsx3.init()
engine.say("I will speak this text")
engine.runAndWait()
```